# convert dataframe to dict, using a column name as key and another columns as k, v - python, pandas, dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thanks in advance by all help.

I have a dataframe like this:

| client_id | product_id | product_name | timestamp_added | product_constraint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | fi2k | loug | 2021 | null |
| abc | fi2j | feb | 2021 | null |
| abc | fkn | ros | 2021 | skn |
| cbd | 01x | get | 2021 | lok |
| cbd | 018 | los | 2021 | hnc |
| cbd | 018 | vng | 2021 | hnc |

I need to do a dict by this df.
Please note that client_id is not unique, event client_id as pk and product_id is not unique. Just the combination of client_id, product_id and product_constraint (that can be null in some cases) make a perfect unique identifier.

My dict needs to be like this:

```
{
    "abc":[
        {
            "product_id":"fi2k",
            "product_name": "loug",
            "timestamp_added": 2021,
            "product_constraint": null
        },
        {
            "product_id":"fi2j",
            "product_name": "feb",
            "timestamp_added": 2021,
            "product_constraint": null
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ],
    "cbd":[
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

After this, i will use this dict to insert data into dynamodb.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    from pprint import pprint
    outdict = {} # create output dictionary

    df = df.set_index('client_id') # set index and group
    dfg = df.groupby(df.index)

    #iterate through groups populating the dictionary
    for grp in dfg.groups:
        g = dfg.get_group(grp)
        # print(g.to_dict('records'))
        outdict[grp] = g.to_dict('records')

    pprint(outdict)

{'abc': [{'product_constraint': nan,
          'product_id': 'fi2k',
          'product_name': 'loug',
          'timestamp_added': 2021},
         {'product_constraint': nan,
          'product_id': 'fi2j',
          'product_name': 'feb',
          'timestamp_added': 2021},
         {'product_constraint': 'skn',
          'product_id': 'fkn',
          'product_name': 'ros',
          'timestamp_added': 2021}],
 'cbd': [{'product_constraint': 'lok',
          'product_id': '01x',
          'product_name': 'get',
          'timestamp_added': 2021},
         {'product_constraint': 'hnc',
          'product_id': '018',
          'product_name': 'los',
          'timestamp_added': 2021},
         {'product_constraint': 'hnc',
          'product_id': '018',
          'product_name': 'vng',
          'timestamp_added': 2021}]}
```